# Permission denied when running docker-compose up on Mac OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having some issues with permissions in my docker-compose, Dockerfile scripts.

This is the error I have when running docker-compose up:

[image]

As you can see I have a "Permission denied" error that prevents my API to be up and running.

This is what my docker-compose.yml file looks like (I skipped the database part because it's not relevant to the problem I have here):

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1338:1337"
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: [
        "docker/api/wait-for-postgres.sh",
        "postgres",
        "docker/api/start.sh"
    ]
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 1337
```

What I've tried so far is changing the permissions and switching to root user inside my container but it didn't change a thing (still have the same error as the one shown in the screenshot above).

```
FROM node:14


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY . /usr/src/app

USER root
RUN chmod +x docker/api/start.sh
RUN chmod +x docker/api/wait-for-postgres.sh

EXPOSE 1337
```

EDIT:

Content of wait-for-postgres.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e
  
host="$1"
shift
  
until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 10
done
  
>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec "$@"


Any thoughts on this ? Thanks for your help !
```

Comment: What's happening in `wait-for-postgres.sh` script? Could you post it?

Comment: Hi @StefanGolubović and thanks for your time spent looking on the project. I just edited my post to add the content of the wait-for-postgres.sh script

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you much. I can give you a couple of advices. First, try running the image built from Dockerfile (`docker container run --rm -it <image name> bash`) and then check permissions for files, try executing the `wait-for-postgres.sh` script (maybe even comment out the loop) and check what happens, does it have an error or does it succeed. Second thing is optional as you'll have to check which one consumes less space (if that concerns you), but you can use [`netcat`](https://serverfault.com/a/819511) instead of `psql` to check if DB is up.

Comment: Also, for some images (I think `alpine` for example) you can't install `postgresql-client` (it is not available in the package repo) and then you'll have to (or could) use `netcat` instead.